# como hacer un INSERT de varios paises

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Nunca se me ha presentado esta situación pero siempre hay una primera vez.

La cosa es que tengo un campo tipo select y necesito llenarlo con una lista de países, ya tengo la lista pero no tengo idea de como hacer un `INSERT`  de esta magnitud en MySQL.

En mi lista de paises hay algunos ciento y tantos o 200 paises y quiero ejecutar esa consulta en una sola query por que ya imaginarán lo tedioso que sería insertarlos uno por uno XD.

Intenté esto pero solo se creó la tabla, no hizo la inserción:

```
$counry=mysqli_query($conexion,"CREATE TABLE `apps_countries` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `country_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL default '',
    `country_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");

    $insert_country=mysqli_query($conexion,"
       INSERT INTO `apps_countries` VALUES (null, 'AF', 'Afghanistan');
       INSERT INTO `apps_countries` VALUES (null, 'AL', 'Albania');
       INSERT INTO `apps_countries` VALUES (null, 'DZ', 'Algeria');
//etc.... a houndred something countries remaining
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues tu sentencia para que quede en un solo `INSERT` debería ser del siguiente modo:

```
INSERT INTO app_countries 
VALUES
(NULL, 'AF', 'Afganistán'),
(NULL, 'MX', 'México'),
(NULL, 'AR', 'Argentina'),
(NULL, 'SP', 'España');
```

> Es decir a tu `query` `INSERT`, le puedes pasar múltiples valores a
>   insertar únicamente separados por comas y estos mismos agrupados entre
>   paréntesis, una vez que lo conluyes lo único que haces es colocar `;`
>   al finalizar como puedes ver en el ejemplo; de este modo aunque insertes múltples valores solo vas a ejecutar un solo `INSERT`

Comment: Gracias funcino bien!!

Answer (score 2):

Hay otra forma de hacerlo: llamando a cada columna por su nombre.

Haciendo esto tendremos dos ventajas:

- Escribiremos un código donde sabremos en cada momento lo que estamos insertando. O lo que es lo mismo, ganamos en claridad.
- Dado que la columna `id` es auto-incremental, podremos omitirla y al mismo tiempo ahorrarnos los `NULL` en la lista de valores, ya que el sistema asignará de forma automática cada valor auto-incremental.

La consulta quedaría entonces así:

```
INSERT INTO app_countries 
    (country_code, country_name)
VALUES
    ('AF', 'Afganistán'),
    ('AL', 'Albania'),
    ('DZ', 'Algeria') 
    ...
```